# iOS App That Delivers Push Notifications for Twitter Hanshtags

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, ios-appstore, twitter, apns

Is there an iOS app (free or paid) that sends push notifications when a new post with a certain hashtag or keyword is tweeted?

I see [Twitterrific](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/twitterrific-5-for-twitter/id580311103?mt=8&uo=4&at=10l4G7&ct=TWITTERRIFIC_SITE_IOS) can send a push notification when I get @mentioned or get a direct message, but I can't see how to configure it to subscribe to a #hashtag and push me a notification.

Can this be done with one app or multiple apps/services?

Comment: I'll flag this to be moved to the [Software Recommendation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) SE site.

Comment: Given the [requirements for asking questions](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) on SR, it might be better to ask a new question there then to migrate that one (and have it closed over there).

Comment: Have you looked into [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com)? For example [this](https://ifttt.com/recipes/213599-if-twitter-hashtag-then-if-notification) (not a dedicated twitter client though).

Comment: I was able to make this happen via IFTTT.  I set up a recipe to send a message to Pushbullet when my twitter account tweets a hashtag.  This works for me since I am wanting to monitor a twitter bot that I control.  But it doesn't seem that I could monitor for hashtags from users besides the account that I link to IFTTT.

Answer (score 2):

iOS apps don't work to filter based on keyword, so you would need an app that has a server side component that reads your stream continually and then sends a push notification to your device.

I would start with IFTTT - https://ifttt.com/ and then look at Pushover - https://pushover.net - if the former doesn't meet your tastes or needs.